# Ext.isIE return false in IE 11

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

When I try to use Ext.isIE in IE11 i get false the returning value. And then during the debug my code I see that I get the following error:
JavaScript Error - Msg:Invalid argument.,
my extjs's version is: 4,2

Comment: When I read the question, I thought IE did it again... LOL !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IE 11 is not officially supported prior to ExtJS 4.2.2 (see property [`isIE11`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-property-isIE11)). Microsoft removed the `MSIE` part from IE11's user agent (refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), which is the reason why it does not work with ExtJS 4.2.1 and below.

From the source code, for [ExtJS 4.2.1](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Ext-more.html):

```
isIE = !isOpera && check(/msie/),
isIE7 = isIE && ((check(/msie 7/) && docMode != 8 && docMode != 9 && docMode != 10) || docMode == 7),
isIE8 = isIE && ((check(/msie 8/) && docMode != 7 && docMode != 9 && docMode != 10) || docMode == 8),
isIE9 = isIE && ((check(/msie 9/) && docMode != 7 && docMode != 8 && docMode != 10) || docMode == 9),
isIE10 = isIE && ((check(/msie 10/) && docMode != 7 && docMode != 8 && docMode != 9) || docMode == 10),
isIE6 = isIE && check(/msie 6/),
```

and for [ExtJS 4.2.2](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/Ext-more.html):

```
isIE = !isOpera && (check(/msie/) || check(/trident/)),
isIE7 = isIE && ((check(/msie 7/) && docMode != 8 && docMode != 9 && docMode != 10) || docMode == 7),
isIE8 = isIE && ((check(/msie 8/) && docMode != 7 && docMode != 9 && docMode != 10) || docMode == 8),
isIE9 = isIE && ((check(/msie 9/) && docMode != 7 && docMode != 8 && docMode != 10) || docMode == 9),
isIE10 = isIE && ((check(/msie 10/) && docMode != 7 && docMode != 8 && docMode != 9) || docMode == 10),
isIE11 = isIE && ((check(/trident\/7\.0/) && docMode != 7 && docMode != 8 && docMode != 9 && docMode != 10) || docMode == 11),
isIE6 = isIE && check(/msie 6/),
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple:

```
navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf('rv:11') > -1
```

will return true if it's a IE11 browser.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

var isIE11 = window.location.hash = !!window.MSInputMethodContext;