# Extjs 4.2 app not loading on IE 11

Tags: javascript, extjs, internet-explorer-11, extjs4.2

We are trying to make our app built on ExtJS 4.2 to be compatible with IE 11. This one currently works very well on Chrome. But when tried with IE 11, throws some errors which are clueless to fix.

Below is the sample console log for the same :

```
SCRIPT257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.
File: ext-all.js, Line: 862, Column: 2
SCRIPT257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.
File: ext-all.js, Line: 862, Column: 2
SCRIPT257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.
File: ext-all.js, Line: 862, Column: 2
SCRIPT257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.
File: ext-all.js, Line: 862, Column: 2
SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught
File: ext-all.js, Line: 5070, Column: 5
SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught
File: ext-all.js, Line: 5070, Column: 5
```

Before hitting URL in IE, I tried with adding the domains to compatibility list, added IE compliant meta tag in Index file, provided the missing references, etc but still not able to load it in IE.

Please let me know if I missed anything OR any additional steps to be taken to make it IE compatible.

Comment: What's the exact version you're using? IE11 is not supported prior to 4.2.2. Microsoft changed IE11's user agent quite significantly, so older versions of ExtJS, such as 4.2.1 (latest GPL), won't detect that you're on IE at all. Also see my answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881671/ext-isie-return-false-in-ie-11/21882477#21882477

Comment: Check any console is added for debug purpose if it added remove it and build once again.

Comment: did you get solution yet ?